# Merge and delete the nodes from overlapping shapes in Inkscape

Tags: vector, inkscape, path

I started my adventures with Inkscape.
I am trying to merge and delete connection between nodes.

I have got a two objects that intersect:

[image]

I would like to merge them and delete a section so the result is similar to this:

[image]

I tried **join selected nodes** for two node from two objects but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question isn't easy to understand, so if I've misunderstood, perhaps you should add more details.

I assume you have two filled closed paths which intersect. In the example below, the red curved shape is on top. I've coloured it red simply so that you can see what's going on easier.

1. Select the red shape, and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (*Copy*)
2. Select both shapes by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and clicking them both.
3. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (*Division*)
4. Delete the middle black piece.
5. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (Paste in Place) to paste the red shape back.
6. Press <kbd>End</kbd> (*Lower to Bottom*)
7. Select the tiny little black piece, and the red shape.
8. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (*Division*)
9. Select the other tiny little black piece on the other side, and the red shape.
10. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (*Division*)
11. Select the middle red piece, and delete it.
12. Select all the shapes on one side and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> (*Union*)
13. Repeat step 12 for the objects on the other side.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your effort. It is exactly this what i expect.

Comment: Unfortunately it fails on step 4 for me. :/ I have no idea what the difference between my image and yours is... I simply cannot remove the middle part like that on my image...